# Returning relevant records which are listed in selected column

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I modify the query in order to get **Expected Result** as shown below?

**TABLE**

```
id    name    posts
1     A       
2     B       3
3     C       1,2
4     D       3,1
5     E       4,1,2
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id IN (SELECT posts FROM table WHERE id = 5)
```

**RESULT**

```
id    name    posts
4     D       3,1
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
id    name    posts
1     A       
2     B       3
4     D       3,1
```

Comment: Stop what you're doing and see normalization.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I'm not allowed to do normalisation in this particular case.

Comment: That is most unfortunate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t2.id = 5 and find_in_set(t.id, t2.posts) > 0);
```

Then work on fixing the database structure.

Comment: Excellent. I didn't know about `find_in_set()`